# Jest await default error handler of express

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, supertest

Given the following setup:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  // explicitly return an error
  return next("my error");
});

// made this middleware for the example,
// solution should typically also work for express default error handling
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  if (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error });
    throw new Error(error); // <- how to test this?
  }
  next();
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("server running on 8080");
}); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

And for the test:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../app.js");

const spy = jest.spyOn(global.console, "error").mockImplementation();

it("throws an error", async done => {
  const res = await request(app).get("/");

  expect(res.status).toBe(500);
  expect(res.error.text).toContain("my error");

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // nothing...

  done();
});
```

Made a Codesandbox with this [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-feather-4v14s?file=/src/index.test.js). Not sure how to run a node test in that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` shouldn't be used with `done`, this results in test timeout in case `done()` cannot be reached.

First of all, error handler shouldn't re-throw an error, unless it's reusable router instance that is supposed to be augmented with another handler. If it's the last one in a row, it should catch both synchronous and asynchronous errors that can happen inside of it.

The problem is that default error handler is [triggered asynchronously](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.17.1/lib/router/index.js#L202) so it should be specifically awaited:

```
it("throws an error", async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(global.console, "error");
  const res = await request(app).get("/");

  expect(res.status).toBe(500);
  expect(res.error.text).toContain("my error");
  await new Promise(resolve = > setTimeout(resolve));
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // it really shouldn't
});
```

A more correct way to approach this is to make sure the error is handled:

```
it("throws an error", async () => {
  const defaultErrorHandler = jest.fn((err, req, res, next) => {});

  app.use(defaultErrorHandler);
  const res = await request(app).get("/");

  expect(res.status).toBe(500);
  expect(res.error.text).toContain("my error");
  expect(defaultErrorHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. removed the 'done' in my tests. About the error handler. If it should not throw, what should it do otherwise?

Comment: It's the terminal point. It should respond with an error and optionally log it,  `app.use(function(error, req, res, next) { res.status(500).send({ error }); console.error(error) })`. `if (error)` is redundant because that's error handler. In case an error is possible in error handler, it should be handled with try..catch - or there should be yet another error handler for it.

Comment: Ah got it. So no throwing errors but (optionally) loggin them. Perfect.