# unable to handle async error in jest when error is thrown in if-else statement

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I used all the techniques to test a route that throws an error in the if statement but I'm unable to pass the test.

```
router.post('/api/users/signUp', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const error = validateAuthInput({ email, password });
  if (error) {
    console.log(error) // "email" must be longer than 5 characters or so
    throw new Error(error);
  }
})
```

I think throwing an error with an if-statement makes my tests fail. I tried every technique to expect an error but unable to test.

```
it('throws an Error', async () => {
  const res = request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signUp')
    .send({ email: 'test', password: 'password' });

  await expect(res).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

The request is handled by supertest library.
I tried all the ways to expect the result but failed to do so.

Comment: Firstly `.rejects.toThrow` doesn't really make sense, rejecting is different to throwing an error. But secondly just throwing an error from the handler isn't how you deal with errors at the API level (and likely isn't going to work at all), you need to respond with a 4xx or 5xx code to tell the client what the problem was. In other words your code and test are *both* wrong.

Comment: Could to tell me how my code and test should be?

Comment: I know .rejects.toThrow() doesn't make sense here but i said i tried multiple ways. So this is just a random try i made

Comment: Well first you need to decide what the response status and maybe body should be, then write a test to `request(app)....expect(status[, body])` per the supertest docs then write the implementation code to get the test passing.

Comment: This is the easiest way i know but i want to test this when i throw an error. I know this is not a good way to tell client what js happening. But i still wanna test this. How should i expect this?

Comment: Again, at the API level it *doesn't* throw an error, it responds with a non-2xx code to tell the client something went wrong. See e.g. https://www.loggly.com/blog/http-status-code-diagram/ for choosing codes appropriately. There's no point testing your current code because it doesn't do the right thing.

Comment: Okok so that means i don't need to throw an error but i should return a response with a status code and some error response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62914782/jest-await-default-error-handler-of-express

Comment: You can throw an error, but as for Express app it's supposed to be emitted with `next` and caught in error handler then. Express doesn't support async functions and promises, so writing a route like that without additional helper is not workable.